# How to validate a user input without form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I would like to check the user input field if he entered 2 decimal number without form submission. The check should happen when just simply coming out from the input field. If he entered without decimals, I want to add .00 to the number. How can I achieve this? can anyone please help?

sample code is here

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Profit Margin: </span><input type='number' step=0.01 placeholder='0.00'  id='ProfitMargin' name=profitmargin  value={$smarty.post.profitmargin}>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">%</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rb746f3g/

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question. This problem has been asked and answered multiple times on this site

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onchange` function. Your code would look like this:

`<input type='number' step=0.01 placeholder='0.00'  id='ProfitMargin' name=profitmargin  value={$smarty.post.profitmargin} onchange='myFunction()'>`

And in the JavaScript:

```
myFunction()
{
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onKeyUp" tag .

This will check validate the textbox the moment you hover out of the text box.

```
<input type='number' step=0.01 placeholder='0.00'  id='ProfitMargin' name=profitmargin  value={$smarty.post.profitmargin} onKeyUp="if((this.value).isInteger()){this.value.toFixed(2)}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseFloat.toFixed(2) method. here 2 is no. of numeric which you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#ProfitMargin").on('blur',function(){
           var current=$(this);
           current.val(parseFloat(current.val()).toFixed(2))
   })
})
```

```html
 


   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Profit Margin: </span><input type='number' step=0.01 placeholder='0.00'  id='ProfitMargin' name=profitmargin  value={$smarty.post.profitmargin} >
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">%</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and do this. You can add the .00, But for whole number integer, JS will remove it every time you convert it back to number type.

```
$("#ProfitMargin")
  .focusout(function() {
    var number = Number($("#ProfitMargin").val());
    alert(number);

        var isInteger = Number.isInteger(number);
    alert(isInteger);

    var floatingNumber = number;
    if(isInteger)
        floatingNumber = number + ".00";
    alert(floatingNumber);

    $("#ProfitMargin").val(floatingNumber.toFixed(2));
  });
```

The best way to achieve this is use text field type but you will loose Step function then. Also your value {$smarty.post.profitmargin} should change to text.

So your code will change to -

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Profit Margin: </span><input type='text' placeholder='0.00'  id='ProfitMargin' name=profitmargin >
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">%</span>

$("#ProfitMargin")
  .focusout(function() {
    var number = Number($("#ProfitMargin").val());
    alert(number);

        var isInteger = Number.isInteger(number);
    alert(isInteger);

    var floatingNumber = number;
    if(isInteger)
        floatingNumber = number + ".00";
    alert(floatingNumber);

    $("#ProfitMargin").val(floatingNumber);
  });
```

Here is a working example - https://jsfiddle.net/s7en2amz/